# Android Studio shortcut lightbulb

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a shortcut to show the lightbulb help window?
Thanks.

[help lightbulb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaQPs.png)

Comment: please check `Writing Code` section in https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, all you have to do is to select a line of code from Android Studio and press **ALT + ENTER** for showing lightbulb's recommendations.